# In Java what would be the more efficient way than stream().forEach() but still using stream operation?

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, java-stream

For example, I have a List of Strings (probably over 5000, and I need efficiency!). And I want to apply the same operation on each of them, e.g. splitting or others.

For now I use

```
List<String> a = ....;
a.stream().forEach(x->{
    //some code here...
    //maybe a split?
    String[] ss=x.split("...");
    Arrays.stream(ss).forEach(y->{...});
});
```

I know it is very unefficient for now, but how can I improve this? Btw parallelStream should not be used!

Edit:
I tried map operations e.g.

```
a.stream.map(x->x.split(...)).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

But it is for more less efficient than using forEach operation, although the code looks much cleaner.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: `a.stream().forEach` can be replaced with `a.forEach`. Other than that, we don't know enough about the code you're working with to provide any better suggestions.

Comment: What kind of efficiency do you need?

Comment: Are you looking for efficiency of code or efficiency of operations? The code you've provided appears to be nested complex forEach, which is really ugly. If you just want to chain a bunch of `forEach` operations, you would be better served using `map` chains towards a final result.

Comment: I'm looking for an efficiency of operations, e.g. 1000 operations under 5s. So like my comment in the first anwser, using map isn't helping a lot.

Comment: Since the nested application of `y->{...}` is an entirely different thing than collecting into a `List<String[]>`, there is no sense in comparing the performance of both. 5000 is not a high number, that’s rather ridiculously low. If processing them takes a significant time, you should post what you are actually doing with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the map function, to map the strings to a desired value, then iterate over them

```
a.stream().map(s -> s.split("...")).forEach(split -> {});
```

Or, you can filter them,

```
a.stream().map(s -> s.split("...")).filter(split -> split.length > 0);
```

Or you can collect them,

```
a.stream().map(s -> s.split("...")).filter(split -> split.length > 0).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

There are many things you can do with streams these are just some examples.

Comment: So I tried your codes the last day but I found that forEach operation is more efficient than map operation. For example `list.stream().forEach(x->listOfArray.add(x.split(...))` is for more efficient than `listOfArray=list.stream().map(x->x.split(...)).collect(Collectors.toList())` So of course using map makes the code cleaner but it doesn't have the efficiency I want.

Comment: How does “there are many things you can do with streams” answer the question “what would be the more efficient way”?